# Scraping or processing results of SQL API calls

Tags: r, api, sqldf, opendata

I ma trying to download data and do some analysis from the following Open Data webpage

```
http://data.ci.newark.nj.us/dataset/new-jersey-education-indicators/resource/d7b23f97-cba5-4c15-997c-37a696395d66
```

They have given some examples like this query example (via SQL statement)

```
http://data.ci.newark.nj.us/api/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT * from "d7b23f97-cba5-4c15-997c-37a696395d66" WHERE title LIKE 'jones'
```

I am using `sqldf` package to read the data but unable to succeed.

Comment: do you want absolutely to use R ? I would recommend python for this dynamic scrapping ...

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel so you haven't seen `httr`, `rvest`, `xml2` in action, eh? SO isn't the place to start religious wars.

Comment: unfortunately the example SQL call (on their site, it's what you pasted but it's not your fault) generates an error in their API. Do you _need_ to use SQL? the other parameter-based ones work (i think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than resort to `rvest` and scraping you can use their API directly. As I said, their SQL example errors out, but it doesn't without the `WHERE…` part (example below). Here are the building blocks for a repeatable process in either straight search or SQL search:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

# for passing in a SQL statement
query_nj_sql <- function(sql=NULL) {
  if (is.null(sql)) return(NULL)
  res <- GET("http://data.ci.newark.nj.us/api/action/datastore_search_sql",
             query=list(sql=sql))
  stop_for_status(res) # catches errors
  fromJSON(content(res, as="text"))
}

# for their plain search syntax
query_nj_search <- function(resource_id=NULL, query=NULL, offset=NULL) {
  if (is.null(resource_id)) return(NULL)
  res <- GET("http://data.ci.newark.nj.us/api/action/datastore_search",
             query=list(resource_id=resource_id,
                        offset=NULL,
                        q=query))
  stop_for_status(res) # catches errors
  fromJSON(content(res, as="text"))  
}

# this SQL does not error out
sql_dat <- query_nj_sql('SELECT * from "d7b23f97-cba5-4c15-997c-37a696395d66"')

search_dat <- query_nj_search(resource_id="d7b23f97-cba5-4c15-997c-37a696395d66")
```

As I said, that SQL query won't error out.

Both calls return a slightly complex `list` structure that you can examine with:

```
str(sql_dat)
str(search_dat)
```

But the records are in there:

```
dplyr::glimpse(sql_dat$result$records)

## Observations: 545
## Variables: 40
## $ Total population 25 years and over                 (chr) "6389.0", "68.0", "4197.0", "389.0", "1211.0", "4...
## $ Male - Associate's degree                          (chr) "286.0", "0.0", "63.0", "6.0", "69.0", "31.0", "7...
## $ Male - Master's degree                             (chr) "148.0", "29.0", "379.0", "17.0", "79.0", "24.0",...
## $ Male - 7th and 8th grade                           (chr) "49.0", "0.0", "16.0", "2.0", "14.0", "0.0", "0.0...
## $ Female - High school graduate, GED, or alternative (chr) "915.0", "0.0", "426.0", "46.0", "174.0", "30.0",...
## $ Male - 11th grade                                  (chr) "88.0", "0.0", "12.0", "0.0", "3.0", "0.0", "0.0"...
## $ Male - Bachelor's degree                           (chr) "561.0", "0.0", "878.0", "93.0", "137.0", "58.0",...
## $ Male - Some college, 1 or more years, no degree    (chr) "403.0", "0.0", "179.0", "23.0", "39.0", "0.0", "...
… (this goes on a while)
```

The API looks like it may paginate, so you may have to deal with that (hence the `offset` parameter).

Since the NJ Edu API supports OData queries, you may be able to use the [RSocrata](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/RSocrata/index.html) package as well.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like their SQL example is working.  But I don't think you need to even use sqldf for this, you can just pull in the data using the RCurl package.

If you want to try a different example, you could use the html API calls they have:

```
library(RCurl)
web <- "http://data.ci.newark.nj.us/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=d7b23f97-cba5-4c15-997c-37a696395d66&q=jones"
page <- getURL(web)
```

And then use html parsing to make the content more understandable.